# working with typescript services and observables: why won't my event handler run?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, service, observers

I'm working with an Angular 2 project. I'm trying to work with observables and services in typescript. I am firing an event but the event handler in my observable is not running.

Here is my code:

The Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

@Injectable()
export class AllDataPageService {

    receptorFilterChanged$ = new Subject<any>();

}
```

The service consist of one event: receptorFilterChanged.

Here is the component that fires the event (located at ~\src\results\app\all-data-page)

```
import { AllDataPageService } from './all-data-page.service';

...

@Component({
    selector: 'all-data-page',
    templateUrl: './all-data-page.component.html',
    styles: [require('./all-data-page.style.scss')],
    providers: [AllDataPageService]
})
export class AllDataPageComponent implements OnInit {

...

    constructor(private allDataPageService: AllDataPageService) {}

...

filterByReceptorTag() {

...

this.allDataPageService.receptorFilterChanged$.next(50.0);

...

}

...

}
```

So it's the line this.allDataPageService.receptorFilterChanged$.next(50.0) in the function filterByReceptorTag() above that fires the event. I have confirmed in the Chrome debugger that this line executes.

Here is the component that handles the receptorFilterChanged event (located at ~\src\results\app\shared\components\all-data-row)

```
import { AllDataPageService } from '../../../all-data-page/all-data-page.service';

...

@Component({
  selector: 'all-data-row',
  templateUrl: './all-data-row.component.html',
  styles: [ require('./all-data-row.style.scss') ],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  providers: [AllDataPageService]
})
export class AllDataRowComponent implements OnInit {

...

  constructor(private allDataPageService: AllDataPageService) {
      this.allDataPageService.receptorFilterChanged$.subscribe(
          (value) => {

...

          }
      );
  }

...

}
```

When the receptorFilterChanged fires, the event handler that I subscribe above does not run.

Can anyone see what might be going on?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "AllDataPageService" is scoped to both the AllDataPageComponent and also the AllDataRowComponent. That means each of these components gets a new instance of that AllDataPageService service.

You should remove the

```
providers: [AllDataPageService]
```

from each of your components and move it to a "Module" instead. That way, you'll only have one instance of your service so they'll be able to talk to each other.

Comment: Thanks Vidal, you were right. As soon as I started passing the service from the AllDataPageComponent to the AllDataRowComponent, it started working.

Answer (score 0):

> Can anyone see what might be going on?

Timing issue. `subscribe` is happening after `next` so doesn't get the original value